# Error: Could not find or load main class (MAC)

Tags: java, macos

I'm following a tutorial on beginning java and trying to run the following:

```
    package Examples;
public class Squares {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Use a Scanner to read from standard in 
        java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        num = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

I'm able to compile it in a folder within a folder on my desktop (learn-java1/ch03/Examples) and create a Squares.class file within the same folder.

But when I try to run it, I get the error: "Could not find or load main class"

I've tried running the following with no success:

**java Squares**

**java -cp . Squares**

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `java Examples.Squares` -- Don't forget the package namespace.